# How stop matching in file lines after the first match

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I need to create a loop that:

1. Reads the content of a files in a list that are in the format Hostname-YYMMDD.txt;
2. Matches specific content in a line within this text file;
3. Stops at the first match (ignores duplicates);
4. Prints specific pieces of this line in an Excel sheet.

This far I fail at point 3.

```
import os
import xlsxwriter
import re

MyPath = "FileDirectory" #e.g. "MyDocuments/Python"
MyHost = "Hostname" # e.g. "Router1_Loc1"
Host_Probes = []

# Loop: Populate Host_Probes []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(MyPath, topdown=False):
    for names in files:
        if MyHost in names:
            Host_Probes.append((os.path.join(names)))

# List with locations of all log files for the TargetHost
Probe_Paths = [MyPath + s for s in Host_Probes]

# Excel file and sheet:
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('MyFile'.xlsx)
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Sheet1')
row = 2 #Row:3
col = 2 #Col:C

# Here I "tell" Python to write the Line that says "CPU utilization" 
# For a given day and then write the CPU utilization for the next day
# in the next column:

for s in Probe_Paths:
    with open (s) as Probe:
        for fileLine in Probe:
            if "Core0: CPU utilization" in fileLine:
                worksheet.write(row, col, int(re.sub('[^0-9]', '', fileLine)))
            elif "Core1: CPU utilization" in fileLine:
                worksheet.write(row +1, col, int(re.sub('[^0-9]', '', fileLine)))
                col +=1
Probe.close()

worksheet
workbook.close()
```

The trouble is that this output is duplicated SOME of the files, thus instead of populating once, it is written twice in the file.

I've not been able to make the loop stop matching for the line with content "Core0: CPU utilization" and "Core1: CPU utilization" after the first time it comes across it.
Is there a way to make Python write only the first match and move to the next string of the list Probe_Paths?

I hope someone can advice.

Comment: You're not defining `fileLine`.

Comment: Your code as given doesn't work at all: `fileLine`, `row`, and `col` are all undefined when they are used, and you're doing nothing with `Probe`. It would be helpful if you include an example of what the lines from your Probe files look look like. It's also not clear what exactly you want to have as your output. Check out [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Notice that `Probe.close()` is redundant, this is handled by the `with` statement.

Comment: glibdud , I believe that this is part of the os module. It works without being defined explicitly anywhere. SBylemans , I need to close it in order to start a new loop afterwards. This is not the only table I need to write on that sheet and the next loop uses another list of strings that is not mentioned here. It did not work until I closed this one. I am not sure why.

Comment: @NathanVērzemnieks thanks for the remark, I fixed it in the example, in the code it is defined. As for fileLine - I never defined it but it works, I took the idea from an example in the forum here and it appears that fileLine is part of the os module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can make a flag variable that indicates if you have already seen the line you want to write

```
for s in Probe_Paths:
    with open (s) as Probe:
        seen = [0, 0]
        if "Core0: CPU utilization" in fileLine and not seen[0]:
            worksheet.write(row, col, int(re.sub('[^0-9]', '', fileLine)))
            seen[0] = 1
        elif "Core1: CPU utilization" in fileLine and not seen[1]:
            worksheet.write(row +1, col, int(re.sub('[^0-9]', '', fileLine)))
            seen[1] = 1
        col +=1

        # have both, can stop looking in the file
        # will not increment col for skipped lines
        if all(seen):
            break
```

Comment: This fixed it!!! Very big thanks, Will! I learned something that will be very useful throughout my entire project :-)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to go is using a dictionary which holds the key eg `Core0: CPU utilization` along with a boolean. Than check that boolean before writing:

```
isWritten = dict()
for key in ["Core0: CPU utilization", "Core1: CPU utilization"]:
    isWritten[key] = false

for s in Probe_Paths:
    with open (s, 'r') as Probe:
        fileLine = Probe.readline()
        if key[0] in fileLine and !isWritten[key[0]]:
            isWritten[key[0]] = true
            worksheet.write(row, col, int(re.sub('[^0-9]', '', fileLine)))
        elif key[1] in fileLine and !isWritten[key[1]]:
            isWritten[key[1]] = true
            worksheet.write(row +1, col, int(re.sub('[^0-9]', '', fileLine)))
        col +=1
```

Comment: This would only write two rows to the worksheet total, no matter how many files there are. Is that what the asker wants? It's not clear.

Comment: In case you want to write one of the keys for every file, you need to move the creation of the dictionary inside the `for` loop, right before the `with` statement.

Comment: My point is just that without a better idea of what the problem really is it's premature to offer solutions.

Comment: I agree that the problem description could have been more clear. However, my belief is that based on the offered solution @Asenski should be able to solve his problem.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion created with the problem description. Basically, I have the lines "Core0: CPU utilization" and "Core1: CPU utilization" 2x times (each) in some text files. I need Python to match the first occurance only and move the the next string (i.e. log file) of the list.